# How to execute multiple models in parallel instead of sequentially?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, executorservice, callable

I have various models and I am executing those models one by one sequentially. I will have around 200 models.

Below is my code where I am executing those models one by one

```
Map<String, List<ServerMetrics>> metricsHolder = new HashMap<String, List<ServerMetrics>>();

for (String alias : serverNames) {
    List<ClientsModel> modelMetadata = getModelAttributes();
    List<MachineInfo> machineInfo = getMachineInfo();

    List<ServerMetrics> metricsList = new ArrayList<ServerMetrics>();

    // calling model one by one sequentially
    // is there any way to make this multithreaded?
    // here modelMetadata size might be 100 or 200
    for (ClientsModel modelList : modelMetadata) {
        String modelValue = modelList.getModelValue();
        String modelId = String.valueOf(modelList.getModelId());

        // execute my model here and storing the metrics in the metricsList object
        ServerMetrics metrics = TestUtils.executeModelMetrics(machineInfo, modelValue);
        metrics.setModelId(modelId);

        metricsList.add(metrics);
    }

    metricsHolder.put(alias, dynMetricsList);
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Is there any way we can make the model execution multithreaded and then store the result into a `metricsList` object?

Comment: If the executions are not interdependent, you can just spawn a new thread for each one and then store the result. Can't you ?

Comment: If I have around 200 models, then do you want me to spawn 200 thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no data race conditions in your code (multi-threaded access to the same data that is not properly synchronized), then you can use a threadpool, in the form of an `ExecutorService`, to run `Callable` implementations on threads. You can do the work in the `Callable`.

On the main thread, the `ExecutorService` returns a `Future` that you can then wait for once all the tasks have been spawned.

The size of the thread pool (here set at `10`, but you can change it) determines how many run in parallel. You can still execute more `Callable`s than the size of the thread pool.

```
    Map<String, List<ServerMetrics>> metricsHolder = new HashMap<String, List<ServerMetrics>>();
    // Size of thread pool set at 10 - can be increased but increasing it 
    // to more than the number of cores on your computer is probably not 
    // useful, as it seems like your task is CPU-bound
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    for (String alias : serverNames) {
        List<ClientsModel> modelMetadata = getModelAttributes();
        List<MachineInfo> machineInfo = getMachineInfo();

        List<Future<ServerMetrics>> metricsFutureList = new ArrayList<Future<ServerMetrics>>();

        // calling model one by one sequentially
        // is there any way to make this multithreaded?
        for (ClientsModel modelList : modelMetadata) {
            final String modelValue = modelList.getModelValue();
            final String modelId = String.valueOf(modelList.getModelId());

            metricsFutureList.add(executorService.submit(new Callable<ServerMetrics>() {
                @Override
                public ServerMetrics call() throws Exception {

                    // execute my model here and storing the metrics in the list
                    ServerMetrics metrics = TestUtils.executeModelMetrics(machineInfo, modelValue);
                    metrics.setModelId(modelId);
                    return metrics;
                }
            }));

        }
        List<ServerMetrics> metricsList = new ArrayList<ServerMetrics>();
        for (Future<ServerMetrics> future : metricsFutureList) {
            metricsList.add(future.get());
        }
        metricsHolder.put(alias, dynMetricsList);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for good suggestion. In your first line you mentioned something about `If there are no data race conditions`, what could cause issue in my code as per your understanding?

Comment: If the models work on the same data (at least one `executeModelMetrics` method updates data that at least one other `executeModelMetrics` reads), then you need to start thinking about multi-threaded synchronisation methods. If multiple invocations of `executeModelMetrics` work on completely different Java objects, or they don't modify Java objects (it's okay if the values have all been set before the thread was started), then you don't have a problem.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Yes in my case, `executeModelMetrics` work on different Java object and they won't modify Java objects so it should be ok.

Comment: But he needs to synchronize access to his `metricsHolder`; it's in danger of corruption by `put()` on multiple threads. This makes it safe: `Map<String, List<ServerMetrics>> metricsHolder = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, List<ServerMetrics>>());`

Comment: @gknicker Not really, since `metricsHolder` is not accessed within multiple threads (only in the main thread)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Hm. Thanks for correcting me. However, I see little benefit in concurrent execution of metrics on a single server. There would be much greater benefit in concurrent execution of the metrics on multiple servers.